# how to transfer large directory from server to remote server?

Tags: unix, ftp, transfer

i have SSH access to my source server on digitalocean and ftp access on my azure server then need to move large directory of images from source server to remote server, how can i do it with FTP or mput or similar commands ?
**i have only FTP access to remote server.**

Comment: What about SFTP? Also, this is a better question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: for the destination i have a SFTP details also but prefer FTP.

Comment: If you have SFTP, then you can use SSH commands like SCP or rsync

Answer (score 1):

start with your source server, go to the directory where you have all the files. Start a FTP session to your remote server. After login type `prompt`
then issue `mput *.*`.

If you want to get files from target server, then you can use `mget`

is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

start FTP connection as follow:

```
FTP
open destination ftp server
```

enter username &
password

```
cd destination folder
lcd source folder path
prompt
mput *.*
```

all the commands must be the above order.